# Basic survey data to .txt files

Tags: php

link to my survey (build in progress) is here: http://dtech.id.lv/aptauja/
Sorry that it is in Latvian language, but I hope you will understand the question.

So far I managed to build design and basic HTML, JavaScript coding of my coffee drinking survey...
When user clicks Submit button "Pabeigt!" collected data is shown in the left side of the page (for now).

What I want to do is that this button creates file user1.txt, user2.txt, user3.txt and so on, inside my server `www/logs/` directory.

Is it possible via PHP and if yes then can you give me some ideas?
I know that these kinds of projects are usually MySQL based, but I want to make it as simple as it can be, without any databases and security...

Thank you, any answer will be appreciated.

P.S the reason for this kind of working model is because I have excel that
Imports and handles multiple TXT files, analyzing their content. And also the lack of MySQL knowledge.

Comment: Check the [file_put_contents function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php). With it you'll be able to create files that contain what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this tutorial will help you:
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileappend.php

the key is "append" to the file... this way you will simply start to build up a log file with all the data you want..

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "New Stuff 1\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "New Stuff 2\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

From the link, this is the bit you want.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we would like you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the [link for reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.